# Responsiveness issue for live search drop down in opencart 2.0.1.1

Tags: css, responsiveness

I have added an extension called "smart search" in my open cart 2.0.1.1 , i need the drop down containing the results for live search to be responsive on every device, how can i do that using css?

link for the extension is : http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=2558

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make Smart search live search results drop down responsive I have used

```
@media queries
```

These queries helped me to get the issue resolved